# Categorizing data from 7 columns into 2

Tags: r

This is my first question from stackoverflow community. I have 7 columns of numerical data with their respective variable names in R. They belong to the same variable i.e. income data collected for 7 years. I want to categorize the data in a way so I have all the numerical data in one column and their respective variable name in the second. How do I do that?

Comment: check out the `stack()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow: Please see this for the future [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

We could use `pivot_longer` from the `tidyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# example data
df <- mtcars %>%
  select(1:7) %>% 
  `colnames<-`(LETTERS[1:7])
  
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = everything()
  )
```

output:

```
   name   value
   <chr>  <dbl>
 1 A      21   
 2 B       6   
 3 C     160   
 4 D     110   
 5 E       3.9 
 6 F       2.62
 7 G      16.5 
 8 A      21   
 9 B       6   
10 C     160   
# ... with 214 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Problem has been resolved.